# How to do iteration inside $scope

Tags: angularjs

i have the code in angular js inside a function:

```
$scope.myNum= [
  {num:'1'},
  {num:'2'},
  {num:'3'},
  {num:'4'},
  { and so on}...
];
```

what i want is an iterative code for the items inside the myNum. Like using for loop etc, but i don't how to do it. I'm new to angularjs.

Thank you.
(edited)

Sorry for the misunderstanding the thing that I'm telling is that somewhat like:

```
$scope.myNum =[
for(i = 1;i<100;i++){
num:'i'}
]
```

Something like a code like this.

Comment: You want to create `$scope.myNum` using loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you mean that you want to create an array of objects containing the numbers 1-100 and then assign that to your scope.

The easiest way to do that would be something like:

```
var items = [],
      i;
for (i = 0; i <= 100; i++) {
    items[i] = { num: i};
}
$scope.myNum = items;
```

Here's it working on [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/R6fqfNzdRflWoHaHCmCk?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

In markup

```
<div ng-repeat="number in myNum">{{number.num}}</div>
```

Go through this link [ng-repeat](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat)

In JS use `angular.forEach()`

```
angular.forEach(myNum, function(value, key){
       console.log(value.num);
     });
```

Comment: See the edit to the question, this is not what OP is looking for

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate inside the `$scope` as well as in usual JavaScript array:

```
var i = 0,
    len = $scope.myNum.length

for ( ; i < len; i++ ) {
    console.log( $scope.myNum[i] );
}
```